# hardware problem

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot

I Repair my window & restart my computer ,it doesnt start & shows "invalid boot ini file' & doesn't take cdrom as first boot divice
Tell me what to do
i have a P3

Comment: Could you please make the title a bit more descriptive?

Comment: Sounds like they did a repair of Windows, now it won't boot from the hard drive or cdrom? Not sure what could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the order of boot devices in BIOS - you can read about how to get into BIOS (the method of which is dependent on your manufacturer) [here](http://michaelstevenstech.com/bios_manufacturer.htm).

Once there you should be able to set your optical drive as the primary boot device. (Move it to the top of the list.)